# Run script over SSH, get input from remote host keyboard

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, stdin, tty

I have a (python) script that waits for user input.
I want to run that script on my raspberry PI that I access over an SSH connection.

I would like to capture the user input via the keyboard that is attached to my raspberry via a USB.

How could I achieve this? I only seem to be able to capture input from the machine that starts the ssh connection.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question more suited to the https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/,

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/562434/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-hosts-keyboard-when-connected-via-ssh